# passing a javascript validation to dynamic textboxes in mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone i am working on a project similar to a shopping cart.I am using the below code to generate textboxes(for selecting the quantity) in my view:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
      <tr>
      <td align="left" class="Text_nocolor">
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.ProductName)                                
       /td>
       <td align="right" class="Text_nocolor" valign="top">
      @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Cart", new { UserID = Request.QueryString["UserID"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
       {               
    <input id="Quantity" type="text" class="Text_nocolor" name="Quantity" value="@item.Quantity"  @*onblur="return NumberOnlyTextBox(event)"*@  onchange="return allownumbers()" maxlength="3"/>  
@Html.Hidden("unitrate", item.Rate)               
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="Text_nocolor" onkeypress="return validateNumbersOnly(e);" onclick="return RegainFocus();" />
       }
```

In the above code "id=Quantity" represents the textboxes.
and i have written a javascript for **numbers only** validation for these textboxes.
These are my javascript functions:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function RegainFocus() {
            if ((document.getElementById("Quantity").value).length == 0) {
                document.getElementById("Quantity").focus();
                alert("Quantity cannot be empty");
                document.getElementById("Quantity").value = document.getElementById("Quantity").defaultValue;
                return false;
            }
            else if ((document.getElementById("Quantity").value) > 100) {
                alert("There is no enough inventory for this product to fulfill your order");
                document.getElementById("Quantity").value = document.getElementById("Quantity").defaultValue;
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function allownumbers() {
            //      var elements = document.getElementsByName('Quantity');
//           for()
            var val = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("Quantity").item(1).value);
            alert(val);
            if (!val || val < 1) {
                alert('Please enter a valid value');
                document.getElementById("Quantity").value = document.getElementById("Quantity").defaultValue;
                return false;
            }
            document.getElementById("Quantity").value = val;
            return true;
        }
     </script>
```

My problem is that the validation **works only for the first textbox** not the others.
Can anyone pls provide a solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try it using the following code snippet:

```
onkeypress="return validateNumbersOnly(this);" onclick="return RegainFocus(this);"
...
function RegainFocus(obj)
{
  if ((document.getElementById(obj).value).length == 0) {
    ..
}
..
```

Hope it helps.